# Restore Previous Version not working

Tags: windows-7, restore, system-restore

Its been around 7 months since I reinstalled the fresh version of Windows 7 on my PC, but the restore previous version is not appearing anywhere: neither on folder nor on any file. whats the Fix?

[image]

Comment: Enable system restore for that drive.

Comment: Can you guide me the steps because I used the last window for 4 years and never did that?

Comment: Is this your C: drive we are referring to? All drives have an individual system restore setting and some drives, like USB or flash may not be capable of system restore depending on format, etc.

Comment: Yes, C Drive sir.+ D drive which is the part of internal hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled system restore on the drives in question:

> To check if you have the protection turned on go to the Control Panel,
>   click System then choose System Protection.
>
> The system properties will appear, click the System Protection tab. 
>   Look for the drive marked with “System” – this is the drive where
>   Windows 7 is installed.  The protection for this drive is on by
>   default – if not, click it to turn it on.  You may turn on the system
>   protection of other non system disks.  If you do this, you can restore
>   previous versions of files inside those drives.

https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-enable-system-restore/

Configure system restore for all drives in question.

Comment: Its look like that now I have successfully completed that → https://ibb.co/n8NSik